# sync a rss feed appointment service for iPhone

Tags: iphone, rss, feed, scheduled-tasks

we have a web application that has a built-in appointment/scheduler feature for our clients. how can i create a web service that users can register in their iPhone to hookup/sync with their schedule/appointments?

I appreciate all comments. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use APNS for this purpose, whenever a new appointment is scheduled you will send a notification to your iPhone app to sync the latest data using the same web service that is used earlier to fetch data.

Comment: hi, but can i just create a standard .ics format service and have pull data from there?